# Writing PHPUnit Test for a function returning an array

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

now a days I am playing with [PHPUnit](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/). I have gone through its documentation but I am unable to understand it well. Let me explain my case.

I have a function in a class which takes three parameters `1 array, 2 some string, 3 a class object`.
This function returns the array by putting second parameter as an index of the array and result as object of that index. My function is as below

```
 public function construct($testArray, $test,$analysisResult) {
    $postedTest = explode('_', $test);
    $testName = end($postedTest);
    $postedTest = implode("_", array_slice($postedTest, 0, -1));
    if (in_array($postedTest, array_keys($testArray))) {
        $testArray[$postedTest][$testName] = $analysisResult;
    } else {
        $testArray[$postedTest] = array($testName => $analysisResult);
    }
    return $testArray;
}
```

If I call this function like

```
    $constructObj = new Application_Model_ConstructTree();
    $test=$this->getMockForAbstractClass('Abstract_Result');
    $test->level = "Error";
    $test->infoText = "Not Immplemented";
    $testArray = Array('databaseschema' => Array('Database' => $test));

    $result = $constructObj->construct($testArray,"Database",$test);
```

The function returns the array like

```
Array
(
 [databaseschema] => Array
    (
        [Database] => AnalysisResult Object
            (
                [isRepairable] => 1
                [level] => Error
                [infoText] => Not Implemented
            )

    )
)
```

Now I want to write a PHPUnit Test to check that the attributes of object like `isRepairable, level and infoText` exists and not empty. I have gone an idea that `assertNotEmpty` and `assertAttributeEmpty` can do some thing But I am unable to understand how to do it.

My test looks like

```
public function testcontruct() {
    $constructObj = new Application_Model_ConstructTree();
    $test=$this->getMockForAbstractClass('Abstract_Result');
    $test->level = "Error";
    $test->infoText = "Not Immplemented";
    $testArray = Array('databaseschema' => Array('Database' => $test));

    $result = $constructObj->construct($testArray,"Database",$test);

    $this->assertNotCount(0, $result);
    $this->assertNotContains('databaseschema', $result);
}
```

Can anyone please guide :-)

Comment: It looks like your problem might just be with the asserts.  These happen when they fail.  Therefore, an assertTrue(Condition) will actually only through the assertion (error) when the Condition is not true.  The assert happens only on failures, so it is as if they are missing the 'only when results is not' from the name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The last line should be `assertContains` instead `assertNotContains`. The next steps in your test would be:

```
$this->assertContains('Database', $result['databaseschema']);
$this->assertAttributeNotEmpty('isRepairable', $result['databaseschema']['Database']);
$this->assertAttributeNotEmpty('level', $result['databaseschema']['Database']);
$this->assertAttributeNotEmpty('infoText', $result['databaseschema']['Database']);
```

`assertAttributeNotEmpty` takes the attribute name and the object as parameters, just as `assertContains` takes the array key and the array.

Comment: Thanks dude. Well explained

Answer (score 4):

I'd use assertArrayHasKey ie:

```
$this->assertArrayHasKey($key, $array);
```

Because you need to test a complex structure, what I'd do is going to each one of the expected elements and assert that they are there, and they are not empty with assertNotEmpty()

I found this a good example, similar to your problem:

http://opensourceame.com/asserting-that-an-array-contains-another-array-in-phpunit/